# Extracting XML in a column from a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have read dozens of posts and have tried numerous SQL queries to try and get this figured out. Sadly, I'm not a SQL expert (not even a novice) nor am I an XML expert. I understand basic queries from SQL, and understand XML tags, mostly.

I'm trying to query a database table, and have the data show a list of values from a column that contains XML. I'll give you an example of the data. I won't burden you with everything I have tried.

Here is an example of field inside of the column I need. So this is just one row, I would need to query the whole table to get all of the data I need.

When I select * from [table name] it returns hundreds of rows and when I double click in the column name of 'Document' on one row, I get the information I need.

It looks like this:

```
<code_set xmlns="">
    <name>ExampleCodeTable</name>
    <last_updated>2010-08-30T17:49:58.7919453Z</last_updated>
    <code id="1" last_updated="2010-01-20T17:46:35.1658253-07:00" 
          start_date="1998-12-31T17:00:00-07:00" 
          end_date="9999-12-31T16:59:59.9999999-07:00">
        <entry locale="en-US" name="T" description="Test1" />
    </code>
    <code id="2" last_updated="2010-01-20T17:46:35.1658253-07:00" 
          start_date="1998-12-31T17:00:00-07:00" 
          end_date="9999-12-31T16:59:59.9999999-07:00">
        <entry locale="en-US" name="Z" description="Test2" />
    </code>
    <displayExpression>[Code] + ' - ' + [Description]</displayExpression>
    <sortColumn>[Description]</sortColumn>
</code_set>
```

Ideally I would write it so it runs the query on the table and produces results like this:

```
Code     Description
--------------------
(Data)   (Data)
```

Any ideas? Is it even possible? The dozens of things I have tried that are always posted in stack, either return Nulls or fail.

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you want to retrieve some of the xml node values, and have the values as fields in a tabular result set, right? Which nodes do you want?

Comment: @ViKiNG I don't think it's a duplicate because OP wants to shred [xml field] for every row returned by the query, not just a single XML document.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    CodeSetId = xc.value('@id', 'int'),
    Description = xc.value('(entry/@description)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
CROSS APPLY
    YourXmlColumn.nodes('/code_set/code') AS XT(XC)
```

This basically uses the built-in XQuery to get an "in-memory" table (`XT`) with a single column (`XC`), each containing an XML fragment that represents each `<code>` node inside your `<code_set>` root node.

Once you have each of these XML fragments, you can use the `.value()` XQuery operator to "reach in" and grab some pieces of information from it, e.g. it's `@id` (attribute by the name of `id`), or the `@description` attribute on the contained `<entry>` subelement.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will read the xml field in every row, then shred certain values into a tabular result set.

```
SELECT
      -- get attribute [attribute name] from the parent node
      parent.value('./@attribute name','varchar(max)') as ParentAttributeValue,
      -- get the text value of the first child node
      child.value('./text()', 'varchar(max)') as ChildNodeValueFromFirstChild,
      -- get attribute attribute [attribute name] from the first child node
      child.value('./@attribute name', 'varchar(max)') as ChildAttributeValueFromFirstChild
FROM  
     [table name] 
      CROSS APPLY
     -- create a handle named parent that references that <parent node> in each row
     [xml field name].nodes('//xpath to parent name') AS ParentName(parent) 
     CROSS APPLY
     -- create a handle named child that references first <child node> in each row
     parent.nodes('(xpath from parent/to child)[0]') AS FirstChildNode(child)
GO
```

Please provide the exact values you want to shred from the XML for a more precise answer.